# Chamar um método de uma classe a partir de uma função dentro da própria classe? C++

Tags: c++, funções, classes, método

Criei a função "checkCase4" na minha classe Tree e dentro dela faço chamadas de 2 métodos da própria classe (rotate_left e rotate_right).

Função:

```
void checkCase4(Node *child, Node *grand) {
 if (child == child->parent->right && child->parent == grand->left) {
  rotate_left(grand, child->parent, child);
  child = child->left;
 }
 else if (child == child->parent->left && child->parent == grand->right) {
  rotate_right(grand, child->parent, child);
  child = child->right;
 }
 checkCase5(child, child->parent->parent);
}
```

Método:

```
void Tree::rotate_right(Node *gr, Node *par, Node *ch){
...
}
```

E me retorna o seguinte erro:

rbt.cpp: In function ‘void checkCase4(Node*, Node*)’:
rbt.cpp:32:44: error: ‘rotate_left’ was not declared in this scope
     rotate_left(grand, child->parent, child);

rbt.cpp:36:45: error: ‘rotate_right’ was not declared in this scope
     rotate_right(grand, child->parent, child);

Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeceria muito.

Comment: Tem algum problema que vai além do que você postou, precisa ver toda estrutura.

Comment: `checkCase4` não parece ser um método de instância. Então, se você quer pedir para a árvore rotacionar, você deve passar a árvore. Mais ou menos assim: `arvore.rotate_left` (para o caso de ter o objeto ou a referência) ou `arvore->rotate_left` (para o caso de ter o ponteiro)